# unable to update column in Sharepoin2013 document library using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

i am using the below code snippet to update the column in the SharePoint document library on button click but not, same code is working for List but not Library. same time am not getting error also

any one try to execute this code in your system and let me know where am missing.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#Button1").click(function(){  

                updateMetadata(1);
    });
});           


function updateMetadata(id) {
alert('buttonIn'+id);
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyDocuments')/Items(" + id + ")";

    alert(url);

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax(

    {

        'url': url,

        'method': 'POST',

        'data': JSON.stringify({

            '__metadata': {'type':'SP.MyDocumentsListItem'},

            'Title': 'Update Field Again'

        }),

        'headers': {

            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',

            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',

            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),

            'X-Http-Method': 'MERGE',

            "If-Match": "*"

        },

        'success': function (data) {
alert('updated'+data);
            var d = data;

            dfd.resolve();

        },

        'error': function (err) {
alert(err);
            dfd.reject();

        }

    }

   );

    return dfd;

}
</script>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Update Metadata"/>
```

Comment: Please add some description to your question. Specify the problem, what part of code u have problem, what research you have done till now?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Patch" instead of "Merge":

```
'X-Http-Method': 'PATCH'
```

Comment: Hi Alok, Thank you for your quick response. but it is not working for both PATCH and MERGE. same time its not giving any error also. i have placed an alert in Success method it is prompting as well.

Comment: Hi Rajendar, pls check deferred implementation as per link http://www.sharepointempower.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=22

Answer (score 0):

```
 '__metadata': {'type':'SP.MyDocumentsListItem'},
```

if your library name is MyDocuments that should be

```
 '__metadata': {'type':'SP.MyDocumentsItem'},
```

Comment: No luck. this one also not resolved my issue. still not updating the item.

Comment: Just to rule this out, if you open /_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyDocuments')/Items in the browser you should get a bunch of xml code. The item type is in there like this <category term="SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem" ... In this example the name of the library is just documents, so it's not necessarily derived from the current library name